# Interpretability of Random Forest Decisions

Tags: random-forest, cart

Decision trees as we know can be easily converted into rules which increase human interpretability of the results and explain why a decision was made. But in case of the random forest when we have many decision trees to get the decision from, will the end results be interpretable i.e. how it came to a conclusion?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The general recommendation for random forest it to use as many trees as possible. In most cases, with hundreds of trees, you wouldn't be able to understand why did they collectively made the decision that they made. In such case, you would need to use the general interpretability tools such as described in the [*Interpretable Machine Learning* book by Christoph Molnar](https://christophm.github.io/interpretable-ml-book/). Among other things, you can also calculate the feature importance for random forests, but beware since the [naive implementations for this are biased](https://explained.ai/rf-importance/index.html).

Comment: I just want to get the theoretical intuition that whether something like this is possible. Do you think if we have a low number of decision trees then we can somehow interpret the decision? or even then it's not possible?

Comment: How do you define that something is interpretable? If you have linear regression, the most "interpretable" model, with thousands of variables it wouldn't be interpretable as well.

Comment: That is an open-end question, even for a single decision tree that is very complex or has loads of features one wouldn't be able to interpret the decision correctly.

Comment: but in case of decision trees its possible that even for complex datasets you would get minimal tree which would be in turn interpretable.